# couchbase data replication elasticsearch

Tags: d3.js, elasticsearch, couchbase

I went through Couchbase xcdr replication documentation, but failed to understand below point:
1. couchbase replicate the all the data in bucket in batches to elstic search. And elastic search provide the indexing for these data for realtime statical data. My question is if all the data is replicated to elsastic search , then in this case elastic search is like database which can hold huge amount of data. So can we replace couchbase with elastic search?
2.how the data in form json is send to d3.js for display statical graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the data is replicated to Elastic Search, but is not held there by default. The indexes and such are created, but the documents are discarded. Elastic Search is not a database and does not perform like one and certainly not on the level of Couchbase. Take a look at [this presentation](http://www.couchbase.com/connect/agenda/integrating-elasticsearch-real-time-kibana/) where it talks about performance and stuff and why Cochbas

Answer (score 0):

If your data are not critical or if you have another source of truth, you can use Elasticsearch only.

Otherwise, I'd keep Couchbase and Elasticsearch.
There is a resiliency page on Elastic.co website which describes potential known problems. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html

My 2 cents.